# Cant get two classes to draw using canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Iam doing my first game for android.

I want to do a very simple thing which is to have a background and a ball that will "spawn" in it.

So I have made my GameView:

```
package com.example.newarkanoid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class Tela extends View {
    Paint paint;
    int x,y;
    int lastx,lasty;
    Bola bola;

    public Tela(Context context, Bola BOLA) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        x=0;lastx=0;
        y=0;lasty=0;
        bola = BOLA;
        bola.paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        bola.invalidate();
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = (int)event.getX();
        y = (int)event.getY();
        if(lastx !=x || lasty !=y){
            lastx=x;
            lasty=y;
            bola.x = x;
            bola.y = y;
            bola.invalidate();
        }
    return false;
    }

}
```

Well, above is my MainDisplay, now i need a ball:

```
package com.example.newarkanoid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Bola extends View {
    Paint paint;
    float x,y,raio;

    public Bola(Context context, float x, float y, float raio) {
        super(context);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.raio = raio;
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, raio, paint);
    }

}
```

So, I did like that cause my teacher told me, you dont have to call invalidate for the intire main display, you can call invalidate just for your ball, so i made my ball drawing code, also its properties.

So as you can see in the code, when i click somewhere in the touchscreen my ball x and y will change to the click position, and then call invalidate.

The thing is, the ball does not even appear when i create my mainDisplay, so I was wondering, is there something like a context problem? why my ball isnt drawn?

Also, here is my MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bola bola = new Bola(this,20,20,5);
        Tela t = new Tela(this,bola);

        setContentView(t);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    bola.invalidate();
}
```

when bola invalidate, bola will draw with its canvas, different the Tela's canvas. You can create a class, not extends view, with draw method

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, raio, paint);
}
```

and call in tela:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    bola.draw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: but the thing is, i'll have to call invalidate to tela, so it will draw all the maindisplay again instead of only the ball, what i wanted was to call bola.invalidate and change its position, leaving background as how it were

Answer (score 0):

use        bola.draw(canvas);        in your onDraw()

Comment: it draws the ball, but how can i redraw only the ball? cause ball.invalidate() dont work